# Cypress alert (pop-up) login at visit url

Tags: authentication, cypress

I have strange problem.
I want to automate one web site using Cypress. At the begining I need to enter credentials like username and password into the alert (pop-up) window. I tryed a lot of ways to handle this.
Here is my code that I used for handling alert (pop-up) windows, that contains input text element:

```js
cy.window().then(($win) => {
cy.stub($win, 'prompt').returns(text)
cy.get(#randomId).click()
})
```

I wasn't sure if this is the correct way to handle this, thats why I tryed one package named: [cypress-ntlm-auth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-ntlm-auth). I tried to use this package, because it seems that the package handles "Windows Authentication login" when visiting a site for the first time. Here is the code that I tried:

```js
cy.ntlm(['chiquito-qa.omnifitrgsites.co.uk'], "tainae", "nekazvam", "chiquito-qa");
cy.visit('chiquito-qa.omnifitrgsites.co.uk');
```

Btw the credentials are not real.

Comment: Hi Ivan, did you want to bypass the login popup or actually complete the popup to test login for the user?
I am trying to do the latter and very stuck.

Comment: I am trying to bypass the login. Login is just "local login". This auth came from the FE - there isn't server side operations. Anyway, the first solution works for me...

Answer (score 6):

you could use this one

```
describe('auth with proper credentials', () => { 
            it('bypass login', () => {
                cy.visit('your url', {
                    auth: {
                        username: 'enter username',
                        password: 'enter password,          
                     },
                })
                
            })
    })
```

Comment: Interesting. I will try it... thanks.

Comment: missed a closing quote. The fact that stackoverflow won't let me add it in a change because a change has to be 6+ characters long is ******* ********

Answer (score 4):

I think the website use a basic authentication method to login simply use this pattern

```
cy.visit("http://username:password@chiquito-qa.omnifitrgsites.co.uk")
```

Or to simplify your process for other request use a base url on the cypress.json file

```
"baseUrl": "http://username:password@chiquito-qa.omnifitrgsites.co.uk"
```

Comment: I tried to use this method -
"baseUrl": "http://username:password@chiquito-qa.omnifitrgsites.co.uk" but its not entering the username and password for the auth pop-up
any idea what shall i do?

Comment: try add http:// to the baseUrl

Comment: Yes I tried with http:// and https:// it dint work for me .

Comment: Try this code 

`/// <reference types="cypress" />

describe("example to-do app", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit("http://username:password@chiquito-qa.omnifitrgsites.co.uk");
  });

  it("displays two todo items by default", () => {});
});`

change the username and password accordingly

Comment: I am using cypress 10 and have mentioned it as base url in cypress.config.js -like this 
'BaseUrl' : "http://username:password@chiquito-qa.omnifitrgsites.co.uk";

Comment: Also - the code you mentioned dint work in my case

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this. This will bypass the auth pop-up and will directly authenticate.

```js
cy.visit('https://username:password@example.com')
```